# QT c++ Ui::HelloQtClass ui

Tags: c++, qt, oop

Ui::HelloQtClass ui;

What is the meaning of this line in the following code of QT c++ application:

```
class HelloQt : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    HelloQt(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~HelloQt();

private:
    Ui::HelloQtClass ui;
    qint32 port;
    private slots:
        void exit();
        void OnClick();
};

#endif // HELLOQT_H
```

Comment: you can read more about QT ui class here http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ui::HelloQtClass ui;` declares the member variable `ui` of type `Ui::HelloQtClass`. `HelloQtClass` is a class in the *namespace* `Ui`. This class will be defined in `ui_helloqt.h`, which is created only after you build your project. (To quickly access the file, select `Ui::HelloQtClass` and press F2, if you're using QtCreator.) This class is generated from `helloqt.ui`, which is generated from QtCreator's Designer, if you're using that.

The `ui` object declares a User Interface for this class, which, because it's derived from `QMainWindow`, is probably what defines what the application's main window looks like, assuming you're following general Qt standards.